# Hibernate error: unexpected AST node

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I need to sort topics by latest post. Could someone please help me with this hibernate query:

```
unexpected AST node: query 
[SELECT t 
FROM Topic t 
ORDER BY 
(SELECT MAX(p.createdOn) FROM Post p WHERE p.topic.id = t.id) 
DESC]
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT topic FROM Post ORDER BY createdOn
```

Comment: this idea helped - fetched data from posts table instead of topics - then just fetched all data - since hibernate fetching all connections and gives objects with .get methods. then grouped by posts.topic.

Comment: I'm happy that it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this JPQL query should work

```
select t.id, t.description, max(p.createdOn) as maxCreationTime 
from Topic t inner join t.posts p
group by t.id, t.description
order by maxCreationTime
```

If you want to include topics that have not related posts.

```
select t.id, t.description, max(p.createdOn) as maxCreationTime
from Topic t left join t.posts p
group by t.id, t.description
order by maxCreationTime
```

You have to specify the selected fields from Topic in order to make the aggregation function `max` work. Hope this helps.